# How to get the Sublime Text 2 Build System to recognize cmake as a valid command?

Tags: cmake, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to get a Sublime Text 2 build system that will ultimately run cmake, make, and then run the C/C++ code. I have 3 directories: src, include, and build(I believe their purposes are self explanatory). For some reason, cmake is not being recognized as a valid command through the build system, but it will in cmd. I've checked both my system path variable and user path variable, and both have the Cmake/bin. So, I have no clue why it would mess up. This is what I've got so far:

```
{
"cmd": ["cd .. && cd build && cmake .. && mingw32-make . && ${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^ *\\[javac\\] (.+):([0-9]+):() (.*)$",
"shell":true
```

}

The directory changes are so cmake runs in the build directory.

This is the output at the ST window: "'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I'm also running on Windows 10.

Comment: Make sure that it's in your `%PATH%`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had that particular session of ST open since before I updated my path. Once I closed out and reopened, all worked as expected.